# Represurise Vaillant Turbomax gas boiler - turning filling screws, but won't fill

Tags: boiler

I have a Vaillant Turbomax boiler (unsure of exact version as I don't have the manual).

The pressure is a little low so I'd like to refill. I've followed these instructions:
http://www.vaillantservice.co.uk/Vaillant_Boiler_Self_Help.html
("Turbomax Filling Loop Mechanism" section)

But nothing seems to happen when I turn both screws 90 deg. I can't hear any water flowing and the pressure isn't changing. Any thoughts? I'm currently on about 0.5 bar. Many thanks

[image: Photo of underside of boiler - screws I turned are visible on right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who experiences the same: It turned out to be a blocked filling loop. We removed the filling loop (flexible silver pipe) and pocked a thin wire through it until the blockage was dislodged. Reattached and all now works fine.